# Could not update; currently locked by another user - MS Access 2000

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a problem with my MS Access database file that is used shared on a network. Sometimes when i try to make an update to the data, is says record locking by 'PC 1'..already try check option same like this picture but still cannot solve. Sometime it locks by itself also cannot open that file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUOJC.png)

Note : Window XP

Answer (score 0):

I also have a MS Access db that is on a shared network.  It is not uncommon for a user to entering data, while another is updated/deleting information within the tables.  If I understand your question correctly, you would like to be able to update the information regardless of whether or not someone else's machine is in the database.

Solution:

Create a db shell that has linked tables to the functional database.  An advantage of this technique is that by having users interact with the shell, you can prevent the database from being locked by a machine.  In addition, it allows multiple users to access and edit the information within the database, without running into record locking issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry i newbie, any tutorial how to create DB Shell.

Comment: In short, you want to have all of your tables in one database (1), then you create another database (2) with all of your forms linked.  In your database (2) you should have all of your forms for updating the tables in database(1).  Hope this helps!

Comment: The following microsoft link should help.  It's called a front-end database, https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-database-2c24eb08-bee1-453e-be8e-455f847c5c74